# button not clickable c# winforms

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

Is it possible to make a button not clickable and just make it clickable when a textbox was filled out, radio button was ticked, checkbox and combo box item was selected?(it needs to be all done before making the button clickable) I already made the button unclickable but I need to make it clickable after filling out informations. Please help, thank you

Comment: Use the property Enable = true/false to enable and disable.

Comment: I've tried that. But I need to get the textboxes, radiobuttons, combo boxes, and check boxes to be filled out. If this will be all true then that's the time that the button will be clickable.

Answer (score 1):

One easy solution might be

1. Disable your button on start up `button1.Enabled=false`
2. Add events to your textbox etc. like `TextChanged` and with the following code.

   ```
        if (!textBox1.Text.Equals(string.Empty) && checkBox1.Checked && comboBox1.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            button1.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            button1.Enabled = true;
        }
   ```

That might work for your case here

Comment: I have many radio buttons, textboxes and checkboxes, is there anyways to code it lesser? They're group inside a groupbox

Comment: You can write a seperat function like 'ChekcIfButtonEnabled' and call it from every update event. That atleast should remove alot of doubled code.

Answer (score 0):

Since your question at this time does not contain code, I will refrain from adding code to the answer and offer you pseudocode to provide one of many possible solutions to this problem.

```
private void Ev_DoCheckEnableButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//check here if textbox is filled, if radio button is ticked, if checkboed is checked and if combobox is selected
//if checks passed set the button to enabled
//if not passed then set it to disabled
}
```

Now for each control you want to check add a listener for the appropriate Event to Ev_DoCheckEnableButton and voila.

Answer (score 0):

First put btnClickable to enable = false, then

basically you need to check if everything is as you need it to be, if it is as you wish, button is being enabled back.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if(cb1.Checked==true && tbText.Text!=null && rb1.Checked==true)
                {
                    btnClickable.Enabled = true; 
                }
            }
```

Note: This is an example where we use ComboBox - SelectionChanged method, because you wrote it last in the ln the question, so i assumed it goes last.

If, for example you want to put checkbox as the last item, just activate Click event on it, and change terms in if(). (ComboBox1.SelectedItem==null instead of cb1.Checked==true))